# Substituting lime juice for lemon juice in hollandaise/mayonnaise?

Tags: substitutions, mayonnaise, lemon-juice, hollandaise

If I have fresh limes on hand but not fresh lemons, can I use the limes to make hollandaise and mayonnaise?  Assuming it works, what effect will the lime juice have on flavor and texture?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it will work. The texture won't be different but the flavor will be significantly different. It will taste like lime hollandaise. :-P

I imagine a lime hollandaise would taste great on fish and other seafood. I'm not entirely sure what you would do with  lime mayonnaise though.

Comment: Sandwiches? I picked up [a jar of lime mayo](http://www.mexgrocer.com/1550-m.html?productid=1550-m) down in SoCal a while back, did a nice job of making bologna sandwiches more interesting. Seems to be a Mexican thing, so I suppose you could throw in some carne adobada or something.

Answer (score 7):

Yes of course you can. As hobodave says above, lime hollandaise would be lovely with seafood, specifically crustaceans, scallops, and skate. Lime mayonnaise would, I think, be lovely in any dish using Mexican or Tex-Mex flavour profiles.